# Ajax load freezes right click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, freeze

So I'm not sure if this has happened before yet to anyone, but in my ajax, I'm loading a bunch of data. Like literally a lot of data. The main problem is on page load, it loads up very fast, but then when you attempt to right click on any part of the page. The right click doesn't work until 5 or so seconds after the whole page is loaded. So after the 5 seconds is loaded, the right click context menu will finally open. It's more of a delay then anything.

Any idea on how to load large amounts of data at the same time not make it delay like that?

Here is my ajax. I know, it's simple.

```
<div id="load_user_data"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#load_user_data').load("ajax/load_user_data.php?load=<?php echo $user; ?>", function() {
    window.setInterval("loadData", 1000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: load data in chunks, chaining ajax load calls and letting the browser to be idle while it waits for ajax response so that it can react to user actions

Comment: @Igor So basically like infinite scroll? I think that's what it's called.

Comment: infinite scroll is one of the applications of this technique

Comment: @Igor Also, would push-and-pull be one of them as well? I know a little bit of infinite scroll, but I kept hearing about push-and-pull so I wanted to know if it's the same thing or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't likely in the AJAX call, so much as it's in the handling of the response of it.

The browser (JS, DOM-rendering, CSS-painting... whole thing) runs on a single thread.  If you lock that thread up, for any reason, everything else (other calculations, DOM rendering...  ...even closing the tab) can hang completely, until that block is gone.

When you make an AJAX call, unless you're using an old-world system, where you ask for synchronous AJAX (*never do this -- 99% of the time, there's a better way*) the AJAX call will block for practically no time; it will make a request, and then disappear, letting the browser keep doing its own thing.
When the server has sent the data, and the browser is finished its current tasks, the AJAX will come back, parse the data, and run whatever tasks you've asked to run afterward.

```
var value = false;
function hasValueFlipped () { return value !== false; }

AJAX.get("data.json", function () {
    console.log("AJAX has returned");
    console.log("flipped now?", hasValueFlipped());
});

console.log("flipped?", hasValueFlipped());
value = true;
console.log("flipped?", hasValueFlipped());
```

should print out:

```
"flipped? false" "flipped? true" "AJAX has returned" "flipped now? true"
```

The thing is, if you're passing megabytes worth of data, that the browser then needs to turn into elements to draw, or perform heavy math, et cetera...  ...that task run on all of that data means your thread is completely blocked, and nothing (clicks, typing, leaving, etc) will work until it's done.

Try either

a) breaking the tasks down into smaller, asynchronous sections

b) breaking the amount of results down into smaller pieces that you request and operate on, one after another